# Google Search optimisation for ajax calls

Tags: ajax, search, indexing

I have a page on my site which has a list of things which gets updated frequently. This list is created by calling the server via jsonp, getting json back and transforming it into html. Fast and slick.

Unfortunately, Google isn't able to index it. After reading up on how to get this done according to [Google's AJAX crawling guide](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html), I am bit confused and need some clarification and confirmation:

The ajax pages need to be implement the rules only, right?
I currently have a rest url like

```
[site]/base/junkets/browse.aspx?page=1&rows=18&sidx=ScoreAll&sord=desc&callback=jsonp1295964163067
```

this would need to become something like:

```
[site]/base/junkets/browse.aspx#page=1&rows=18&sidx=ScoreAll&sord=desc&callback=jsonp1295964163067
```

And when google calls it like this

```
[site]/base/junkets/browse.aspx#!page=1&rows=18&sidx=ScoreAll&sord=desc&callback=jsonp1295964163067
```

I would have to deliver the html snapshot.

Why replace the ? with # ? 
Creating html snapshots seems very cumbersome. Would it suffice to just serve simple links? In my case I would be happy if google would only index the things pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've misunderstood the AJAX crawling guide.  The `#!` notation is to be used on links to the **page** your AJAX application lives within, not on the URL of the service your appliction makes calls to.  For example, if I access your app by going to `example.com/app/`, then you'd make page crawlable by instead linking to `example.com/app/#!page=1`.

Now when Googlebot sees that URL in a link, instead of going to `example.com/app/#!page=1` – which means issuing a request for `example.com/app/` (recall that the hash is never sent to the server) – it will request `example.com/app/?_escaped_fragment_=page=1`.  If `_escaped_fragment_` is present in a request, you know to return the static HTML version of your content.

Why is all of this necessary?  Googlebot does not execute script (nor does it know how to index your JSON objects), so it has no way of knowing what ends up in front of your users after your scripts run and content is loaded.  So, your server has to do the heavy lifting of producing a HTML version of what your users ultimately see in the AJAXy version.

So what are your next steps?

**First**, either change the links pointing to your application to include `#!page=1` (or whatever), or add `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to your app's HTML.  (See item 3 of the [AJAX crawling guide](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html).)

When the user changes pages (if this is applicable), you should also update the hash to reflect the current page.  You could simply set `location.hash='#!page=n';`, but I'd recommend using the excellent [jQuery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) to help you manage the page's hash.  (This way, you can listen to changes to the hash if the user manually changes it in the address bar.)  Caveat: the currently released version of BBQ (1.2.1) does not support AJAX crawlable URLs, but the most recent version in the Git master (1.3pre) does, so you'll need to [grab it here](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/blob/master/jquery.ba-bbq.js).  Then, just set the AJAX crawlable option:

```
$.param.fragment.ajaxCrawlable(true);
```

**Second**, you'll have to add some server-side logic to `example.com/app/` to detect the presence of `_escaped_fragment_` in the query string, and return a static HTML version of the page if it's there.  This is where Google's guidance on [creating HTML snapshots](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/html-snapshot.html) might be helpful.  It sounds like you might want to pursue option 3.  You could also modify your service to output HTML in addition to JSON.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaination. I've learnt a good bit. My main (personal) beef with this whole approach is, that I have to generate the content both on the server using c# and javascript on the client. Keeping two libraries in sync ist just simply error prone..

Comment: @AyKarsi: Yeah, it's extra work for us, but it's the way the world works right now.  The good news is that [they're working on making Googlebot index AJAX pages](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/faq.html#whatifnot) without any extra work on our part.  So hopefully this all won't be necessary in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've more or less given up on this. There really seems no alternative to generating the html on the server and delivering it in the html bdoy if you want goolge to index your directory.

I even tried adding a  section wraped a .net user control which implemented a simple html version of the directory. But google also managed to ignore ..

So in the end my directory has been de-ajaxified. :(